# How to backpropagate transposed convolution with stride and padding

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, backpropagation, convolution

Please, help! I have deadlines and I do not have time to figure out the topic on my own.

And now about the problem. I'm currently trying to figure out back propagation in transposed convolution. I already managed to figure it out and understand that in order to calculate the gradients, you just need to do the reverse convolution operation, that is, if you use the usual convolution, then you need to use the transposed convolution to calculate the gradients, and if you use the transposed convolution, then vice versa, you need to use the convolution. In other words(where X - input; V - kernel, Z - output; d - gradient, rotated180 - matrix rotation):

**For Convolution**

[image: dV = convolution(X; dZ)]

[image: dX = trans. convolution(dZ; rotated180(V)]

**For Transposed Convolution**

[image: dV = trans.convolution(X; dZ)]

[image: dX = convolution(dZ; rotated180(V)]

The problem is that I'm using transposed convolution with stride and padding. And if I could find out how to calculate gradients taking into account the stride and padding in a regular convolution, then I did not have time to figure out how to calculate in a transposed convolution. More (where padding - padding just like in a regular convolution; interweave - adding a zero after every row and every column in a matrix):

**For Convolution with stride 2 and padding 1**

[image: dV = convolution(padding(X); interweave(dZ))]

[image: dX = trans. convolution(dZ; rotated180(V)] but with stride 2 and padding 1

**For Transposed Convolution with stride 2 and padding 1**

[image: dV = transposed.convolution(???)]

[image: dX = convolution(dZ; rotated180(V)] but with stride 2 and padding 1

Actually, I can’t exactly calculate the error gradient with respect to the weights (kernel) of the transposed convolution. I really hope someone can help me.

I tried both adding padding and doing interweave, but it did not give me the desired result.